# string concatenate for global variable

Tags: php, string, loops

I have fetched the value from database using query and trace the variable using foreach.  I want to get the mail id append with the variable `$cc_test`.

Initially the variable is empty. for first iteration `test@sample.com` 2nd iteration `test1@sample.com` and for 3rd `test2@sample.com`.

Finally I want to get `test@sample.com,test1@sample.com,test2@sample.com`, but now I get '`test2@sample.com,test2@sample.com`'.

`$cc_check` is an indexed array `print_r($cc_test)` in for loop prints `test@sample.com` for 1st and `test1@sample.com` for 2nd and so on.

```
$cc_check=asset_status_tracker::where('request_id','=',$data['id'])->where('status_before','!=',null)->get();
$cc_test=''; //dump requestor mail id
foreach($cc_check as $cc_inner){
    $cc_mail=$cc_inner->changed_by;
    print_r($cc_mail);
    $cc_test=users::where('id','=',$cc_mail)->first()->mail;
    $cc_test=$cc_test.','.$cc_test;
    //print_r($cc_test); 
}
print_r($cc_test); //test@sample.com,test1@sample.com,test2@sample.com
```

Comment: ya it's an array

Comment: In each loop you do `$cc_test=users::where('id','=',$cc_mail)->first()->mail;` so you lose what was in $cc_test in every loop.  Makes sense that you see only the test2@sample.com email.  Change that line to `$cc_test2=....` and in the concatenation below (next lline) do `$cc_test=$cc_test.','.$cc_test2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you don't need a counter, you just need to concatenate all of the values using commas as glue.

You can do this without excess commas or iterating conditions by running implode() after the loop is finished.

Save the emails in an array, and implode the array to generate a string of comma-separated values.

Code:

```
$emails=[];
foreach($cc_check as $cc_inner){
    $emails[]=users::where('id','=',$cc_inner->changed_by)->first()->mail;
}
$email_string=implode(',',$emails);
echo $email_string;
```